# How does one control what numericUpDown displays, 1 and not 1,0, while keeping 0,5 percision?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, numericupdown

I have configured my numericUpDown control to have 0,5 precision. (from 0 to 10.)

```
-changed decimalplaces to 1
-changed increment to 0,5
-maximum at 10
-minimum at 0
```

When the value is incremented, I see:

```
0,0
0,5
1,0
1,5
...
10,0
```

What I want is:

```
0
0,5
1
1,5
...
10
```

Is there any simple way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: is this WindowsForms, WebForms, something else...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you Handle in the `ValueChanged` event and change the `DecimalPlaces` property to compare when you value is rounded value.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Winform `NumericUpDown` control and `override` its `UpdateEditText` method as shown on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921446/having-text-inside-numericupdown-control-after-the-number) to a similar question here on SO.

Your class might look like this:

```
public class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown 
{
    public NumericUpDownEx() {
        // Optionally set other control properties here.
        this.Maximum = 10;
        this.Minimum = 0;
        this.DecimalPlaces = 1;
        this.Increment = ,5m;
    }
    protected override void UpdateEditText() {
        // Remove any trailing ',5'.
        this.Text = this.Value.ToString().Replace(".0", string.Empty);
    } 
}
```

An advantage to the approach is that you're creating a new control you can use in other projects.

Comment: That could replace unintended characters if there are more than one decimal digit.  In UpdateEditText, I would check if the string representation contains the decimal separator, and use TrimEnd('0')

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin If the user is able to enter numbers freely then yes this approach would have problems.  I'm assuming the OP is already handling this (perhaps the control's `ReadOnly` property = true) but using `TrimEnd('0')` as you suggest would leave the decimal separator behind when it did its work.

Comment: @Jay Riggs Good point, it would need to be TrimEnd('.', '0').  Your code is perfect for the OP's case, but as it's reusable I thought it was worth mentioning the limitation.