# How to use custom UI elements in designer mode?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to use a NumericUpDown box with custom text in my form, so I followed the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921446/having-text-inside-numericupdown-control-after-the-number). The code compiles and run perfectly!

However, I can no longer view my form in Designer mode to adjust the UI, etc. When I try to, MSVC2008 complains that it "Could not find type 'NumericUpDownEx'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built."

My code is exactly the referenced solution's (as my initial test) and the only other change I have made otherwise is tweaking the InitializeComponent method slightly so it reads

```
this->nudData = gcnew NumericUpDownEx();
```

instead of

```
this->nudData = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::NumericUpDown();
```

Any help would greatly appreciated! ...making UI by code alone really sucks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to make it work. I needed to specify the full namespace name of my new, extended control:

```
this->nudData = gcnew MyProject::NumericUpDownEx();
```

And that's it! Might just be a quirk of this old version of Visual Studio?